# join three tables by SQL and Php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, join

I have these 3  tables in mysql database (also i didn't know it's completely normalized or not?

or is there any better way to design this tables to get this query?)

```
create table T_Users(
     id int
     name varchar (50)
     picture varchar (11)
);
create table T_Groups(
     id int
     name varchar (50)
     admin_id int
);
create table T_Group_Users(
     u_id int
     g_id int
);
```

Now I Want to get all of groups that a specified user joined, with all of members of this groups with them detail(name and picture)
And create an array like this by Php (this is an example):

```
$groups = [ // Groups user by id = 1 joined 'em
        [
            'id' => 1,
            'name' => 'G_1',
            'member' => [
                ['name' => 'R', 'picture'=>''],
                ['name' => 'S', 'picture'=>'14.jpg'],
                ['name' => 'X', 'picture'=>'']
            ]
        ],
        [
            'id' => 5,
            'name' => 'G_3',
            'member' => [
                ['name' => 'T', 'picture'=>'11.jpg'],
                ['name' => 'S', 'picture'=>'14.jpg']
            ]
        ]
    ]
```

(specified user determined by id, `u_id` is foreign key `T_Users` And `g_id` is foreign key `T_Groups`)

Comment: @emineminems I don't understand where I should place id ? 
this query just return `false`. tables are not empty

Comment: if table are not empty , then it should gives the result with appropriate id.

Comment: @mohit-kumar No the query have  bug in `T_Groups.g_id = T_Groups`
T_Groups haven't g_id

Comment: Typo `ON T_Groups.id = T_Group_Users.g_id`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want ids, you can do:

```
select g_id, group_concat(u_id)
from t_group_users gu
group by g_id
having sum(u_id = ?) > 0;
```

This returns each group on a row with a list of the ids of the users in the group.

If you want the names, you an `join` in the appropriate tables.

EDIT:

To get the names and other information:

```
select g.id, g.name,
       group_concat(u.name, ':', u.picture)
from t_group_users gu join
     t_users u
     on gu.u_id = u.id join
     t_groups g
     on gu.g_id = g.id
group by g.id, g.name
having sum(u.name = ?) > 0;
```

Here `?` is for the parameter that has the name.

Comment: `SELECT t_groups.*, member FROM t_groups
        Left JOIN t_group_users ON t_groups.id = t_group_users.g_id where t_group_users.u_id = 1
        (SELECT t_users.* FROM t_users
        Left JOIN t_group_users ON t_group_users.g_id = t_groups.id) AS member` This Not work but i think that i want is something like this....